# display the data from databse according to the difference in date in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two field in a database table `departureDateTime and arrivalDateTime` and the values like

```
departureDateTime=03/18/2012 1:05 PM 

arrivalDateTime=03/18/2012 3:15 PM
```

I have hundreds of records in the table.

I need to sort and display according to the duration from these two time. I know to calculate the duration from two dates

```
Duration=(strtotime($arrivalDateTime') - strtotime($departureDateTime))/3600
```

But how I write a mysql query to sort and display these 100 records from database

Does any one any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your departureDateTime to DATETIME instead of varchar or whatever you are currently using. Then you would use something like this:

```
SELECT other, stuff, TIMEDIFF(departureDateTime, arrivalDateTime) as theDifference FROM myTable ORDER BY theDifference ASC LIMIT 0, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you kept your date and times in a date time column type then you wouldn't have this problem. Consider changing.

There are mysql functions to calculate dates and time too
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

If not, you can do sorting  in PHP using usort.